# Virtualbox host only network only show ipv6 address

Tags: virtualbox

I have ubuntu VM on Virtualbox with host-only network. When I run ifconfig I notice VM's address only have ipv6 address. What could be wrong? I need ipv4 address for my VM.
[Here is my VM's interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXbFo.png)

my VBOX version is 5.1.26